# How to get Distinct List

Tags: flutter, dart

I found online soluton like this:

```
import 'package:queries/collections.dart';

void main() {
  List<String> list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d"];
  var result = new Collection(list).distinct();
  print(result.toList());
}
```

But, I don't know how to convert `var result` back to `List<Widget>`.

Answer (score 15):

There is a way that is a lot easier and does not require any additional imports.
You can convert your `List` to a `Set` which inherently only contains **distinct** elements and then convert that `Set` back to a `List`.

If you are using *Dart 2.3* or higher (`environment: sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"`), you can use the following idiomatic version:

```
List<String> list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd'];
List result = [...{...list}];
```

The `...` spread operator for iterables was [just introduced with Dart 2.3](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47).

Otherwise, you can just use old syntax:

```
List<String> list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d"];
List result = list.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: Or just `var result = list.toSet().toList();`

Answer (score 2):

In this example, we are going to show you how to remove duplicates from an array List of objects by matching it property value in Dare or Flutter.

**Object Model Class:**

```
    class User {
        User({
            this.name,
            this.age,
            this.userClass,
        });
    
        String? name;
        int? age;
        int? userClass;
    
        factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
            name: json["name"],
            age: json["age"],
            userClass: json["class"],
        );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "name": name,
            "age": age,
            "class": userClass,
        };   
}
```

**List of Objects:**

```
List<User> users = [
    User(name: "Deepak Gupta",age:21,class:12),
  User(name: "Vishal",age:21,class:12),
  User(name: "Punnu",age:21,class:12),
  User(name: "Deepak Gupta",age:21,class:12),
  User(name: "John Cena",age:21,class:12),
];
```

**How to Make List of Object Unique?**

```
var set = Set<String>();
List<User> uniqueUser = users.where((e)=> set.add(e.name)).toList();
```

Comment: this one good resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer,
Here is the full code, i try to modify your method but not working.
(Works only in print)

```
      Future<List<List<Widget>>> getList(List<int> list, String column) async {

    List<Widget> list1 = List();
    List<Widget> list2 = List();
    List<Widget> list3 = List();

    //test
  List<String> testlista = List();
  testlista.add(result[0][column].toString());

    List<List<Widget>> listFromDB = [list1, list2, list3];
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'books.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

      var result = await database.rawQuery(
          'SELECT DISTINCT $column FROM planner WHERE id = ${list[i]}');

    //here polulate new List
    testlista.add(result[0][column].toString());


      if (list[i] < 18) list1.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
      if (list[i] > 17 && list[i] < 50)
        list2.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
      if (list[i] > 49) list3.add(_item(result[0][column].toString()));
    }

  //Now this give me corect print list without duplicate!!!
  for (int i = 0; i < testlista.length-1; i++) {
  print('FROM DELETE method: '+ deleteDuplicate(testlista)[i]);   


}



    await database.close();
    return listFromDB;
  }




   //Method for removingDuplicate

   List<String> deleteDuplicate(List<String> lista) {
    // List<String> result = Set.from(lista).toList();
    List<String> result = {...lista}.toList();
    return result;
  }
```